# Eloquent hasmany relationship issue

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, relationships, lumen

I am building an API with the lumen micro-framework using Eloquent for the database.

When i use this code to get the shoppinglists from a group, everything works

```
$group =  Group::with(['shoppingLists' => function($query) {
        }])->get();
```

It returns the following object

```
{
        "id": "797799c2-6044-4a3a-a3a6-a71fbb17de68",
        "name": "'t snackske",
        "description": "best group ever",
        "user_id": "7e74223a-ea06-46bf-ab1a-abb01b287e32",
        "created_at": "2015-08-09 20:06:40",
        "updated_at": "2015-08-09 20:06:40",
        "shopping_lists": [
            {
                "id": "2423eb3c-7dab-4672-b382-895788dec6a0",
                "name": "shop",
                "description": "food",
                "user_id": "7e74223a-ea06-46bf-ab1a-abb01b287e32",
                "group_id": "797799c2-6044-4a3a-a3a6-a71fbb17de68",
                "created_at": "2015-08-09 20:06:40",
                "updated_at": "2015-08-09 20:06:40"
            }
        ]
}
```

And when I check the queries that are logged i get the following queries:

```
{
    "query": "select * from `groups`",
    "bindings": [],
    "time": 0.31
},
{
    "query": "select * from `shopping_lists` where `shopping_lists`.`group_id` in (?)",
    "bindings": [
        "797799c2-6044-4a3a-a3a6-a71fbb17de68"
    ],
    "time": 0.34
}
```

But when i try select specific fields for the shoppinglists this query returns no records
The query builder:

```
$group =  Group::with(['shoppingLists' => function($query) {
            $query->addSelect('id', 'name', 'description');
        }])->get();
```

The response:

```
{
        "id": "797799c2-6044-4a3a-a3a6-a71fbb17de68",
        "name": "Group",
        "description": "testgroup",
        "user_id": "7e74223a-ea06-46bf-ab1a-abb01b287e32",
        "created_at": "2015-08-09 20:06:40",
        "updated_at": "2015-08-09 20:06:40",
        "shopping_lists": []
}
```

The queries from the getQueryLog function

```
{
    "query": "select * from `groups`",
    "bindings": [],
    "time": 0.23
},
{
    "query": "select `id`, `name`, `description` from `shopping_lists` where `shopping_lists`.`group_id` in (?)",
    "bindings": [
        "797799c2-6044-4a3a-a3a6-a71fbb17de68"
    ],
    "time": 0.32
}
```

When i copy and paste the last query from the query log in mysql i get the correct row. For some reason, eloquent doesn't show the data from the shopping_lists.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Group extends Model
{
    protected $increments = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'description',
        'user_id'
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    /**
     * Get shoppinglists from this group
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function shoppingLists()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ShoppingList', 'group_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Comment: The same column name is shared by both tables, so you may need to explicitly state the table name in the select statement. `$query->addSelect('shoppingLists.id', 'shoppingLists.name', 'shoppingLists.description');`

Comment: I have tried using this with '`$query->addSelect('shopping_lists.id')` with no success. And normally this shouldn't be an issue because the `with()` function in a query builder executes a second statement. @Jeemusu

Comment: You might have to add the `group_id` column to the `addSelect()` method for the foreign key constraint to be realised.

Comment: I'll try it out tonight. Can't access my computer at the moment. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to add the foreign key column to the addSelect() method for Laravel to do it's magic.

```
Group::with(['shoppingLists' => function($query) {
    $query->addSelect('id', 'group_id', 'name', 'description');
}])->get();
```